# Recreating the Enter Button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, textbox, enter

There is a page in which wherever you press Enter a textbox appears (type text). If you write something in that box and you press Enter the message will be sent. You don't have to be already focused on that box.

What I wanna do is recreate the Enter function. So if I have something already written in that box and run my script the message will be sent.

I tried this

```
const input = document.querySelector("#messageBox");
const event1 = new KeyboardEvent('keypress', { key: 'Enter' });
const event2 = new KeyboardEvent('keypress', { key: 'l' });
const event3 = new KeyboardEvent('keypress', { key: 'Space' });
const event4 = new KeyboardEvent('keypress', { key: 'Escape' });

messageBox.focus();

setTimeout(() => {
     input.dispatchEvent(event1);
     input.dispatchEvent(event2);
     input.dispatchEvent(event3);
     input.dispatchEvent(event4);
}, 1500)
input.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
     console.log("testing this");
     if (event.keyCode === 13) {
          console.log("Enter has been pressed");
     }
     if (event.keyCode === 76) {
          console.log("L has been pressed");
     }
     if (event.keyCode === 32) {
          console.log("Space has been pressed");
          input.dispatchEvent(event1);
     }
     if (event.keyCode === 27) {
          console.log("Escape has been pressed");
     }
})
```

and saw that none of these events were actually triggered inside the messageBox. When I run the script these 4 keys are pressed but nothing in the messageBox changes. The only thing that changes is in the console in where I see 4 times the "testing this" message. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMk11.png)

Now if I press L, Enter or Escape in that box, it doesn't show their respective console messages. But if I press space, it does show the "Space has been pressed". [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfGgk.png)

Even though I'm new to JavaScript I have searched it a lot and couldn't find anything. I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

[The `KeyboardEvent` constructor documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent) says:

> key Optional
>
> A string, defaulting to "", that sets the value of KeyboardEvent.key.

It **just** sets the value of `key`.

The value of `keyCode` **isn't** implicitly set.

Your event listener logs *testing this* (which you can see) and then tests `keyCode`.

If you want to trigger an event which you can examine the `keyCode` of then you need to set `keyCode` as well as / instead of `key`.

---

Note that `keyCode` is deprecated so your listener shouldn't be using it in the first place.

Comment: I changed all the keyCode to key and I tested all the cases for Enter (keydown, keypress, keyup). Nothing was printed in the console

If I'm not mistaken Enter in my situation should be keydown but again the following doesn't work:

const input = document.querySelector("#messageBox");
const enter1 = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'Enter' });
input.dispatchEvent(enter1);
input.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
                if (event.key === 13) {
                    console.log("Enter (keydown) has been pressed");
                }

Am I missing something here?

Comment: So you set the `key` to be `”Enter”` and then you test to see if it is `13` and it doesn’t match. Why would it? `13 !== “Enter”`!

Comment: Damn, this didn't even crossed my mind. So it shows in the console that "Enter (keydown) has been pressed" but it doesn't actually send the message as it should (as far as I understand). If I hit the physical Enter key, the message will be sent.
I also tried to send 2 events on keydown and right after on keyup, but it didn't work either.

Comment: What does "the message will be sent" mean? Are you expecting an event being triggered to also do the other things that Enter will do (e.g. submit a form)?

Comment: That textbox that I am aiming for isn't in some kind of a form. I had in my mind that if I press Enter virtually it will be the same as pressing the physical Enter button. And after the virtual Enter has being pressed, will happen whatever was going to happen if I had pressed the physical button.

Comment: That isn't how events work. They just trigger any event listeners that exist.

Comment: So if I want to trigger that event listener I must find it in the code, prevent its function and execute it from my own script? Or there is a workaround that I'm not familiar with?

Comment: I now have no idea what you are trying to acheive.

Comment: There is a site in which if you press Enter (anywhere in the DOM) a textbox will appear. If you press Enter again (anywhere in the DOM, could be at the top of the page or could be inside that textbox), whatever text there is inside that textbox will be sent. 

I'm trying to replicate the physical Enter function with a virtual one, which will happen only when I click a button that I created name "Enter". 

So basically I want to replicate the physical Enter whenever I click the "Enter" button I created. With this way I hope for the message to be sent.

I hope I explained it well enough.